# Interface for a set of classes whose objects are only created by implementations of another interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, visitor-pattern

I have a set of data model classes, e.g. DataModel1, DataModel2 and so on. The parameters that are part of each data class are totally different. The only thing common about these data classes is the objects which are going to use their values.
I have an interface 'Investigator', and only different implementation of these Investigator can use different type data of above model classes.

Initially I was having an empty interface for all data classes, like this

```
public interface DataModel {}
```

But then I realised that my scenario fits the visitor pattern.
So, I made changes as below:
I now have a DataModel interface

```
public interface DataModel {
    void accept (Investigator investigator);
}

public class DataModel1 implements DataModel {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;

    @Override
    public void accept(Investigator investigator) {
        investigator.investigate(this);
    }

}

public class DataModel2 implements DataModel {
    private String attribute3;
    private String attribute4;

    @Override
    public void accept(Investigator investigator) {
        investigator.investigate(this);
    }

}
```

and an Investigator interface:

```
public interface Investigator {
    void investigate(DataModel dataModel);
}

public class Investigator1 implements Investigator {

    @Override
    public void investigate(DataModel dataModel) {
        // do some investigations of Type 1 here
    }

}

public class Investigator2 implements Investigator {

    @Override
    public void investigate(DataModel dataModel) {
        // do some investigations of Type 2 here
    }

}
```

Now, for any kind of investigator and data model implementations,
I just have to do:

```
dataModel.accept(investigator)
```

and the correct type of investigation will be done.

Now, my problem comes when I want to actually return a result from the investigation that was done.
Similar to above requirements, an Investigator can return different types of InvestgationResult, so I have the interface and its implementations:

```
public interface InvestigationResult {
}

public class InvestigationResult1 implements InvestigationResult {
    public String investigationText1;
    public String detailedResults1;
}

public class InvestigationResult2 implements InvestigationResult {
    public String investigationText2;
    public String detailedResults2;
}
```

and the Investigator interface be changed to:

```
public interface Investigator {
    InvestigationResult investigate(DataModel dataModel);
}
```

Here, an instance of a InvestigationResult implementation is only created by an Investigator implementation class. (once Investigator completes the investigation, he builds the investigation results)
My question here is that I don't want the 'InvestigationResult' interface to be am empty interface, but I am not very sure what common method it should contain?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first code block does not compile. Specifically, the `accept` methods do not override the interface. Can you show the working code?

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks for taking a look at my query and pointing out these mistakes, I have corrected the problems with the code.

Comment: I suspect the question in the title is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since the code shown does not match the problem statement. Rather than fixing this mock example, can you show real data models and some of the real investigate logic that uses different models?

Comment: The fact that the two interfaces return completely different objects, implies that they are being consumed differently, so why do you want them to have any relation to one another?

Comment: @jaco0646 I have provided most of the earlier code in the problem to give more context. My only question  is how to I make provide a common interface for a set of classes (InvestigationResult1, InvestigationResult2), which will only be created and returned by implementation of a particular interfaces (implementations of Investigator interface).

I have updated the title to bring it more in line with the question.

Comment: The description states that data models have different attributes, but the data models shown have identical attributes. The description states the `Investigator` handles different data models in different ways, but the code shown handles only one interface and includes no logic to differentiate data models. Since the code does not match its description, it's impossible to say whether the Visitor pattern is appropriate at all. If indeed the Visitor pattern turns out to be a poor fit for the actual problem, then the question of what it returns is moot. Thus the XY problem.

Comment: To phrase it another way: this Visitor implementation is incomplete. Rather than focus on _why_ this mock example does not fit the pattern, I suggest returning to the original problem, i.e. handling diverse data models. Ask _that_ question rather than asking how to fix this Visitor.